# Powershell SQL Remove DB access from list

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Hi hope someone can help i have a list of users and instances they have access to in a text file like below.

```
SQL-UAT-DB       domain\testuser
SQL-Prod-DB      domain\Joe.bloggs
SQL-Train-DB     domain\Mary.smith
```

I want to pass this file into DBtools powershell command  "Remove-DbaLogin"
https://docs.dbatools.io/Remove-DbaLogin

example of remove-dbalogin is below where you can state the instance and then login i know i can pass 2 separate files to this one for users and one for instances but i want it to pick both up from one file instead.

Remove-DbaLogin -SqlInstance $instances -Login $userlist

How can i pass this one list to this command and have it remove the login based on each line in the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can just loop through the lines in the file, and call `Remove-DbaLogin` on each.

```
$lines = Get-Content "YourPath";

foreach ($line in $lines) {
    $line;
    $values = $line.Split(" ", [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries);
    Remove-DbaLogin -SqlInstance $values[0] -Login $values[1];
}
```

A more efficient option would be to group up the users by instance, and pass multiple users in one go

Comment: What if the separator is a TAB character instead of multiple spaces?

Comment: Then you do `$line.Split("``t",` that's a single backtick just can't show it in the comments